# newbie question: Why the selected value from dropdown menu does not pass to my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model "MyObject" which contains a property called 'color', this property value is selected from the list of COLORS=['red','black','yellow']. In my application, I have get one instance of "MyObject" from database and show it on the page as a row. I use the 'select' form helper in rails 3, and allowed user to select the color from a dropdown menu.

I used the form helper in this way:

`select("myobject", COLORS, { :include_blank => false })`,

On the view page, I successfully get the colors as a drop down menu with the default value as the selected one.

**BUT**, when I select another color from the menu and press save button, the "myobject" passed to my controller always hold the default color value instead of the selected one, why??

I use `button_to("save", myobject_path(myobject), :method=>:put)` which will pass the object to my controller.

in side my controller, update method:

```
class MyobjectsController < ApplicationController
...
def update

     @myobject = myobject.find(params[:id])

     if @myobject.update_attributes(params[:myobject])
      puts @myobject.color #always get default value
      redirect_to myobject_path
    else
      redirect_to myobject_path
    end
  end
...
end
```

Anybody can explain me why I always get default color value instead of the selected one?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full view code I'm not sure of this, but most likely it's that your form that contains the `<select>` isn't actually being submitted and that `button_to` is simply creating its own form and submiting. You should put the `myobject_path(myobject), :method => :put` on the form itself, not the submit button. And don't use `button_to` for this, use [`submit_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-submit_tag) or something.

Comment: Hi, I did not use form, because I have only color property of my object need to be shown in a drop-down menu style. My object instance is show in a table row, not a form. Only 'color' property needs to be in a <select>, do you mean I can also use form for a single property of a object?

Comment: Yes, you can (and should) use a form even for a single property. A form doesn't have to have any particular look, so you can put as much or as little as you want into it.